# Are 'file data' and 'file size' committed to disk together or separately

Tags: c, file-io, synchronization, filesize, robustness

Consider this example:

```
FILE* stream = fopen("my_file", "w");
fputs("hello", stream);
```

What can happen if power is lost during the execution of fputs()?

Afterwards, could I ever find "my_file" with non-zero size but with the first byte not being 'h'?
If yes, is it guaranteed to be zero, or could it contain an arbitrary value?

Assume, of course, that nobody else is touching our file.

EDIT: Assume also that the target disk drive/device is of a type that is able to keep power long enough to write all the data that it has buffered internally.

Does POSIX have anything to say about this? Does Linux? Does Windows?

EDIT: It was not my intention to focus on the details of how the STDIO streams API is implemented. Assuming POSIX, here is what I really mean:

```
int fd = open("my_file", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
write(fd, "hello", 5);
```

EDIT: POSIX considers the size as meta data for the file, so the question could probably be rephrased as: Can the file data and the meta data for that file ever be committed to disk in separate stages as a result of the code above?

EDIT: Found this in http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html:

> 7.5 Filesystems With Safe Append Semantics
>
> Another optimization introduced in SQLite version 3.5.0 makes use
>   of "safe append" behavior of the underlying disk. Recall that
>   SQLite assumes that when data is appended to a file (specifically
>   to the rollback journal) that the size of the file is increased
>   first and that the content is written second. So if power is lost
>   after the file size is increased but before the content is
>   written, the file is left containing invalid "garbage" data. The
>   xDeviceCharacteristics method of the VFS might, however, indicate
>   that the filesystem implements "safe append" semantics. This
>   means that the content is written before the file size is
>   increased so that it is impossible for garbage to be introduced
>   into the rollback journal by a power loss or system crash.

This seems to provide at least a partial answer.

Comment: [How SQLite deals with atomic commits](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to `linux`, contents you write to the buffer is not guaranteed to be written to the disk immediatley.

The `kernel` copies the `data` into a `buffer` and later in the background, the kernel gathers up all of the `dirty buffers`, sorts them optimally and writes them out to `disk`.This is called `writeback`. This allows write calls to occur lightning fast, returning almost immediately. It also allows the kernel to `defer writes` to more `idle periods` and batch many `writes together`.

Comment: Good info, but my question was specifically about whether a file could end up having its size increased from zero but its contents never written due to, for example, a power failure. I imagine that the answer to this question has a lot to do with the intricate details of how the kernel performs this `writeback` procedure. And I was hoping that, for example, POSIX did state some guarantees in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This depends largely on the file system in use (`ext3`, `ext4`, `xfs`, ....) and the mount-time options given to it, so there isn't an easy one-size-fits-all answer. Perhaps if you show us your `/etc/fstab` and tell us which file system you want to know about, a better answer could be given...

Comment: If possible I would prefer not to consider the specifics of particular file systems. I will have to assume that it can be any of the popular ones. But I guess that what you are also saying is that with some filesystems, it is indeed possible to find "my_file" with non-zero size but with the first byte not being 'h' after a power loss. If you have any details to provide for 'ext4', for example, it would be nice.